# MASS MicroSystems MO/128 Magneto-Optic Drive mystery

Tags: storage, atari-st

I found this drive in one of Atari lots. Apart from few mentions in old articles I can't find any info whatsoever. Can you help please?

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

[image: Disks]

Comment: Open it up and check to see if there's anything significant between the SCSI connector on the back and the drive itself.  If it's just a cable connecting them internally, then what it says on the box doesn't really matter, you just need to find out what the actual drive is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can't find any info whatsoever.

Most likely that's just a standard SCSI case (like [Ross Ridge already assumed](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11430/mass-microsystems-mo-128-magneto-optic-drive-mystery/11431#comment34938_11430)), notable due the existence of a terminator and an ACSI to SCSI cable (maybe even a homed made one). Being a rather standard drive it no hits may turn up in conjunction with Atari - in fact, there where zillions (almost) of shops that created their own brand by putting standard drives into standard cases and added their label. Also, SCSI never made the same huge sales as raw disks or IDE ones.

The drive could be a Pinacle [3.5" MOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto-optical_drive) drive. A as HP had dimples on the lid, Fujitsu a rounded insert and Sony's drives were full height.

Since ACSI is a strict subset of SCSI (*1), a single drive standard  SCSI drive can be attached without minimal effort (*2). All you need would be some TOS driver for this device. Chances are good that even the standard removable hard disk driver for Ataris [Syquest](https://www.atarimagazines.com/startv4n8/syquest.html) based Megadrive 44 will work - it might need some tweeking to recognise the drive and capacity.

---

Now if you really want to dig deeper into Atari ACSI and drives, the [Atari Document Archive](https://docs.dev-docs.org/) may offer much insight about [harddisks](https://docs.dev-docs.org/htm/search.php?find=_H).

---

*1 - Most important reduced address range (max. 4 devices) and only very basic protocol phases (no detach, Atari is always the master and alike) - [see here](http://www.atari-wiki.com/index.php/ACSI,_SCSI_and_IDE#Some_important_differences_between_ACSI_and_SCSI:) for more details.

*2 - Ofc, using a 'real' ACSI to SCSI adaptor (thereare several,some still ailable, like [this one](https://shop.inventronik.de/index.php?id_product=12&controller=product&id_lang=1)) may be the better way. Then again, considering that there is already a D19 to Centronics attached, it might be already made to work out of the (missing) box.